# Merge worksheets using PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

I want to merge worksheets from multiple excel sheets into 1 worksheet in a new excel file.

I referred to the discussion https://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/390898

I did not understand what MarkBaker meant by using toArray(). I mean how do I use it.
My Current Code is:

```
$file1="file1.xlsx";
$objPHPExcel1 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file1);
$file2="file2.xlsx";
$outputFile = "output.xlsx";

$objPHPExcel2 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($file2);
$sheet = $objPHPExcel2->getActiveSheet();
$objPHPExcel1->addExternalSheet($sheet);

$objWriter = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($objPHPExcel1); 
$objWriter->save($outputFile);
```

With this I am able to get different worksheets of various files into a new workbook but as different sheets.

What should I do to get it all onto the same sheet like vitman said?
first_excel_file_with_one_worksheet
--empty line--
second_excel_file_with_one_worksheet
--empty line--
etc.

Answer (score 0):

// update from office site

```
$filenames = array('doc1.xlsx', 'doc2.xlsx');

$bigExcel = new PHPExcel();
$bigExcel->removeSheetByIndex(0);

$reader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($input_file_type);

foreach ($filenames as $filename) {
    $excel = $reader->load($filename);

    foreach ($excel->getAllSheets() as $sheet) {
        $bigExcel->addExternalSheet($sheet);
    }

    foreach ($excel->getNamedRanges() as $namedRange) {
        $bigExcel->addNamedRange($namedRange);
    }
}

$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($bigExcel, 'Excel5');

$file_creation_date = date("Y-m-d");

// name of file, which needs to be attached during email sending
$saving_name = "Report_Name" . $file_creation_date . '.xls';


// save file at some random location    
$writer->save($file_path_location . $saving_name);

// More Detail : with different object:
```

Merge multiple xls file into single one is explained here: 
I'm going to describe a bit different:
http://rosevinod.wordpress.com/2014/03/15/combine-two-or-more-xls-files-as-worksheets-phpexcel/